# Test if a function with multiple if/else blocks return true or false in javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm not sure if this question has been asked before or not,
I'm trying to make a validation form using Javascript.

My question is: is there any way to test if my functions validateEmailLogin() and validatePsswordLogin() returns true or false in all if/else blocks, so I can test in the function isValide() whether the two functions return true or false and do a treatment.

Ps: it's a bit messy code and any suggestions to reduce it and make it cleaner are welcome.

Here's my html and js code :

```
    function validateEmailLogin() {
    var emailInput = document.getElementById("email").value;
    var emailMessageEmpty = document.getElementById("emailEmptyMessage");
    var emailMessagePatern = document.getElementById("emailEmptyPaternMessage");

    if (emailInput == "") {
        emailMessageEmpty.classList.remove("d-none");
    } else {
        emailMessageEmpty.classList.add("d-none");
        
    }

    if (!(emailInput.includes("@") && emailInput.includes("."))) {
        emailMessagePatern.classList.remove("d-none");
    } else {
        emailMessagePatern.classList.add("d-none");
    }
    
}


function validatePsswordLogin() {
    var passwordInput = document.getElementById("password").value;
    var passwordMessageEmpty = document.getElementById("passwordEmptyMessage");
    var passwordMessagePatern = document.getElementById("passwordPaternMessage");
    var Patern = /^[A-Za-z]+$/;

    if (passwordInput == "") {
        passwordMessageEmpty.classList.remove("d-none");
    } else {
        passwordMessageEmpty.classList.add("d-none");
    }

    if ((passwordInput.length < 8)) {
        passwordMessagePatern.classList.remove("d-none");
    } else {
        passwordMessagePatern.classList.add("d-none");
    }

    if (Patern.test(passwordInput)) {
        passwordMessagePatern.classList.remove("d-none");
    } else {
        passwordMessagePatern.classList.add("d-none");
    }
}



function isValide() {
   
    if (validateEmailLogin() && validatePsswordLogin()) {
        window.location.href = "file:///C:/Users/amin/Desktop/Projet-edits/Projet/home.html";
        return false;
    } else {
        alert('check your credentials');
    }
}
```

My HTML

```
form name="loginForm" method="POST">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="email">Email <sup class="text-danger">*</sup></label>
          <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" onfocusout="validateEmailLogin()" name="loginEmail"  placeholder="Entrer votre email" >
          <p id="emailEmptyMessage" class="text-danger mt-1 mb-0 d-none"><small>Le champ email est vide</small></p>
          <p id="emailEmptyPaternMessage" class="text-danger mb-0 mt-1 d-none"><small>Le champ email Doit contenir '@' et '.'</small></p>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="password">Mot de passe <sup class="text-danger">*</sup></label>
          <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" onfocusout="validatePsswordLogin()" name="login-password" placeholder="Mot de passe" >
          <p id="passwordEmptyMessage" class="text-danger mt-1 mb-0 d-none"><small>Mot de passe est vide</small></p>
          <p id="passwordPaternMessage" class="text-danger mt-1 mb-0 d-none">
            <small>Les mots de passe doivent contenir au moins 8 caractères, y compris des majuscules, des minuscules et des chiffres.</small></p>
        </div>
        <button onclick="return isValide()" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary-color w-100">Connecter</button>
        <p class="mt-2">Pas encore membre? <a href="register.html">S'enregistrer</a></p>
      </form>
```

Comment: Welcome!
You are not returning a value from your functions!

Comment: @iAmOren thanks, i tried to do that but it doesn't work

Comment: Got deeper into your code and made suggestions - see my answer.

Comment: This would usually be addressed through testing and looking at your code coverage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I like your code!
The message holders = nice!

I've made some modifications:

- added `valid` flag initialized as `true`, set to `false` when not valid, and returned from both validate functions
- changed `isValide` to `valide` and removed the return
- removed the `<form>`
- removed `type=submit` from button
- button just calls `valide` - whatever is needed to be done - from there
- commented out change of `href` for demonstration - uncomment when ready, actually, use `location.replace(URL);` instead of `window.location.href = URL;`

Notes:

- your URL is a local file...
- the email validator function is not complete (x@.com@.com - passes, for example...)

```js
function validateEmailLogin() {
    var valid=true;
    var emailInput = document.getElementById("email").value;
    var emailMessageEmpty = document.getElementById("emailEmptyMessage");
    var emailMessagePatern = document.getElementById("emailEmptyPaternMessage");

    if (emailInput == "") {
        emailMessageEmpty.classList.remove("d-none");
        valid=false;
    } else {
        emailMessageEmpty.classList.add("d-none");
    }

    if (!(emailInput.includes("@") && emailInput.includes("."))) {
        emailMessagePatern.classList.remove("d-none");
        valid=false;
    } else {
        emailMessagePatern.classList.add("d-none");
    }
    return valid;
}

function validatePsswordLogin() {
    var valid=true;
    var passwordInput = document.getElementById("password").value;
    var passwordMessageEmpty = document.getElementById("passwordEmptyMessage");
    var passwordMessagePatern = document.getElementById("passwordPaternMessage");
    var Patern = /^[A-Za-z]+$/;

    if (passwordInput == "") {
        passwordMessageEmpty.classList.remove("d-none");
        valid=false;
    } else {
        passwordMessageEmpty.classList.add("d-none");
    }

    if ((passwordInput.length < 8)) {
        passwordMessagePatern.classList.remove("d-none");
        valid=false;
    } else {
        passwordMessagePatern.classList.add("d-none");
    }

    if (Patern.test(passwordInput)) {
        passwordMessagePatern.classList.remove("d-none");
        valid=false;
    } else {
        passwordMessagePatern.classList.add("d-none");
    }
    return valid;
}

function valide() {
    if (validateEmailLogin() && validatePsswordLogin()) {
      alert("valid");
//        window.location.href = "file:///C:/Users/amin/Desktop/Projet-edits/Projet/home.html";
    } else {
        alert('check your credentials');
    }
}
```

```css
.d-none {
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<!-- form name="loginForm" method="POST" -->
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="email">Email <sup class="text-danger">*</sup></label>
        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" onfocusout="validateEmailLogin()" name="loginEmail"  placeholder="Entrer votre email" >
        <p id="emailEmptyMessage" class="text-danger mt-1 mb-0 d-none"><small>Le champ email est vide</small></p>
        <p id="emailEmptyPaternMessage" class="text-danger mb-0 mt-1 d-none"><small>Le champ email Doit contenir '@' et '.'</small></p>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="password">Mot de passe <sup class="text-danger">*</sup></label>
        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" onfocusout="validatePsswordLogin()" name="login-password" placeholder="Mot de passe" >
        <p id="passwordEmptyMessage" class="text-danger mt-1 mb-0 d-none"><small>Mot de passe est vide</small></p>
        <p id="passwordPaternMessage" class="text-danger mt-1 mb-0 d-none">
            <small>Les mots de passe doivent contenir au moins 8 caractères, y compris des majuscules, des minuscules et des chiffres.</small>
        </p>
    </div>
    <button onclick="valide()" xtype="submit" class="btn btn-primary-color w-100">Connecter</button>
    <p class="mt-2">Pas encore membre? <a href="register.html">S'enregistrer</a></p>
<!-- /form -->
```

Comment: That's exactely what i was looking for thanks for the boolean part, if i remove the return from the onclick event window.location.href doesn't work any more not sure why

Comment: Glad to help, @AmineMissaoui!
Thanks for the accept!
2 more reputation points and you can up-vote as well!!!

Comment: Use `location.replace(URL)` instead of `window.location.href = URL`.

Comment: even with location.replace i need to add return it's fine to me as long as the other page is loading